# How Long For An Object To Catch Up To Another Object Moving At Different Speeds?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity, speed

Example: A bear is 10 m away from a person, the bear is moving at a speed of 15 m/s, the person is moving at a speed of 6 m/s, how long would it take for the bear to catch up to the person? 
I'm not the best at this stuff, so I'd also like an explanation if anyone knows the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance (in metres) travelled by the person after $t$ seconds is

$
x = 6t
$

while the distance travelled by the bear in the same time $t$ is

$
x = 15t - 10
$

where we must subtract 10 since the bear is initially 10 meters behind the person. Setting these two distances equal to each other gives the time when the bear catches up to the person:

$
6t = 15t - 10
\implies
10 = 9t
\implies
t = \frac{10}{9}
$

Hence the bear and person meet after about 1.1 seconds.

Comment: I don't understand why $6t = 15t - 10$ becomes $10 = 9t$

Comment: Adding 10 to both sides of the equation gives $6t+10=15t$. Then, if you subtract $6t$ from both sides, you find $10=9t$. Dividing both sides by 9 gives the final answer of $t=10/9$.